# How to fix ReText crash while using preview powered by WebEngine (Chromium) renderer?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl

On  a computer with pretty old Nvidia GeForce 9600 GT and Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS MATE using Marco (Compton GPU Compositor) I have installed ReText text editor with actions below:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo -H pip3 install retext
```

and got latest 7.0.4 version installed.
It works as expected, but if I select *Edit→Use WebEngine (Chromium) renderer* to view live preview of my Markdown document it shows completely black window and then crashes (the crash result does not depend on its contents).

The crash log in the terminal is:

```
$ retext demo.md 
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
Using configuration file: /home/norbert/.config/ReText project/ReText.conf
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
[1013/141341.612478:WARNING:stack_trace_posix.cc(699)] Failed to open file: /tmp/.glx5hP6o (deleted)
  Error: No such file or directory
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 0000000001ad
#0 0x7f6cab07052f <unknown>
#1 0x7f6ca9aa1b1d <unknown>
#2 0x7f6cab070a3e <unknown>
#3 0x7f6cbc67d390 <unknown>
#4 0x7f6c5b302321 <unknown>
#5 0x7f6ca9b03c09 <unknown>
#6 0x7f6ca9aeec68 <unknown>
#7 0x7f6cabbac69d <unknown>
#8 0x7f6ca9df26d1 <unknown>
#9 0x7f6ca9df3ec5 <unknown>
#10 0x7f6cac062a67 <unknown>
#11 0x7f6cad87c605 <unknown>
#12 0x7f6cab0d8ee5 <unknown>
#13 0x7f6cab0d4280 <unknown>
#14 0x7f6cbc6736ba start_thread
#15 0x7f6cbc3a941d clone
  r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 0000000000000000 r10: 00007f6c122d8e78 r11: 0000000000000000
 r12: 00000000000000f5 r13: 000000000000000a r14: 000000000000009a r15: 000000000000000a
  di: 0000000001d92264  si: 0000000000000001  bp: 00007f6c64ff8590  bx: 0000000001d8a6d0
  dx: 0000000000000019  ax: 0000000001d92250  cx: 0000000000000001  sp: 00007f6c64ff8530
  ip: 00007f6c5b302321 efl: 0000000000010202 cgf: 0000000000000033 erf: 0000000000000004
 trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 00000000000001ad
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ReText/converterprocess.py", line 62, in _converter_process_func
    job = receiveObject(conn_child)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ReText/converterprocess.py", line 31, in receiveObject
    sizeBuf = recvall(sock, 4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ReText/converterprocess.py", line 24, in recvall
    raise EOFError('Received 0 bytes from socket while more bytes were expected. Did the sender process exit unexpectedly?')
EOFError: Received 0 bytes from socket while more bytes were expected. Did the sender process exit unexpectedly?
```

other possible behavior is to have black window and the following repeating text in the terminal:

```
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
Could not link shader program:
 ""
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed: 
""
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(qt_Matrix): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed: 
""
...
```

I suspect that OpenGL causes the issue. But `swrast` driver is installed:

```
$ dpkg -S swrast
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
```

The `nvidia` driver is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm             36864  0
nvidia              10571776  50 nvidia_uvm
drm                   364544  3 nvidia
```

and has 340 version (the [last legacy supported one for my 9600 GT](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/135161/en-us)):

```
$ modinfo nvidia_340 | head -n3
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-104-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_340.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        340.104
```

The output of `glxinfo | egrep -i "vendor|^direct"`

```
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
```

VA info is also OK:

```
$ vainfo 
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.39 (libva 1.7.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Splitted-Desktop Systems VDPAU backend for VA-API - 0.7.4
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

What else should I try to fix the issue?

Notes:

1. this seems to be problem with OpenGL<->Xorg<->Qt interaction with Nvidia. This Chromium preview works normally on the laptop with Intel i915 and on desktop with AMD/ATI APU.
2. of course the version from official repository (ReText 5.3.1 (using PyMarkups 1.0.1)) works as expected with both renderers - default and WebKit.
3. switching to software compositor in `mate-tweak` does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to switch from OpenGL provided by PyQt5 to PyOpenGL.
So we need to install this package using `pip3`:

```
sudo -H pip3 install PyQt5==5.9.2
sudo -H pip3 install PyOpenGL
```

We need to edit `/usr/local/bin/retext` and add here one line `from OpenGL import GL`. We can do this programmatically:

```
sudo sed -i "s/^from ReText.window import ReTextWindow$/from ReText.window import ReTextWindow\nfrom OpenGL import GL/" /usr/local/bin/retext
```

Then ReText should work normally and will have synchronized scrolling of editor and preview.

---

Also I filed [bug/feature-request](https://github.com/retext-project/retext/issues/399) to ReText developer via GitHub.